# Delete in multiple lines - ag-grid - axios - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, ag-grid

I have an "AG-GRID" table that requests with using "axios" in the database.

I can do "GET" and "PUT" in one row, but I need to DELETE in several rows of this table, but I don't know how to do it.

Example of POST or PUT method in table:

```
save(event) {
    const method = event.data.id ? 'put' : 'post'
    console.log(event.data)
    axios[method](`${baseApiUrl}/instituicao/${event.data.id}`, event.data)
        .then(() => {
            this.$toasted.global.defaultSuccess()
        })
        .catch(showError)
        console.log("teste", event.data.id)
},
```

Comment: How do you want to delete multiple? By clicking the column you want?

Comment: @RenatoManalili I need to delete the lines that were selected from "checkboxSelection: true"

Comment: @RenatoManalili I would like to apply a vuejs method that deletes the selected rows when clicking a button.

Comment: @RenatoManalili up

Comment: Please someone can help-me?

Comment: Give me clear instruction so that I can help you.

Comment: @RenatoManalili Sorry, I need to create a button to delete the selected lines. I can already select rows through the property (rowSelection = "multiple")

Comment: Do you have a repository for that? coz I will help you. email me at manalili123@gmail.com

Comment: @RenatoManalili I send your e-mail

Comment: I haven't receive any email sir.

Comment: I send your e-mail: manalili123@gmail.com

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't receive any email.